# Fatal error: Maximum execution exceeded

Tags: php, wamp

I am trying to import a large database into my WAMP 2.5 server phpmyadmin. After importing some tables an error occurs:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.class.php on line 285

and the importing process is stopped. I have already increased `max_execution_time` in my php.ini file. Can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Comment: so either raise the limit, disable it entirely, or split your job into smaller bits that fit within your limit. those are your only practical choices. And honestly, what exactly are you expecting us to be able to help with? "Have you tried 361 seconds? How about 362?"

Comment: If you start the import abput phpmyadmin you can disable the max runtime for only the import

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't modify the `php.ini` file !

Modify the **alias of the phpMyAdmin** file : `J:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

Before the line `</Directory>`, you can describe what you want :

```
php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

You can change the **values of time or size as you want**.

Comment: If you changed the value in php.ini with no luck (error still saying 360) check this file, line 26 (might be in your C:\ drive)

Comment: this is the right solution in my opinion, but i ended up splitting my import files into a 100,000 entries each anyway... just to make them more manageable.

Answer (score 6):

You can also forget about phpMyAdmin completely and use the `mysql console`

Using the wampmanager icon menus do the following :-

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL Console
```

If you have changed the password for the root userid enter that when challenged or if you have not changed it just hit enter.

Make sure there is a `USE databasename` in the backup file, if not enter it manually now and then use the `source` command to run the restore from your backup file.

i.e.

```
USE YourDatabase;
SOURCE C:/path/to/backup/file.sql;
```

Note the use of UNIX directory seperators even though you are on windows.

This tool has no time limitations as its not a PHP script, and will run to the end of your backup with no issues.

Comment: much better than the one that is marked as answered

Comment: @MurtazaMandvi Thanks, but for a beginner the accepted answer is probably easier, especially as WAMPServer 2.5 comes with those exact settings pre-configured and just increasing them is very simple. Most beginners get a little frightened by the command line.

Comment: Very helpful, had no idea about this very useful facility. Always missed mysql < source.sql type functionality on my local wamp setup. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although strongly not recommended, you can remove the maximum script run-time restriction by setting `max_execution_time` to zero:

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

If there's a more reliable way for you to get the file onto the server (SFTP?) I would suggest you try that first.