# Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Im trying to backup a wordpress website from host and move it back on my local host and keep it as a sample for rebuilding. If have any workaround or maybe other methods I`m all ears

I backedup my website and database also, but when I`m trying to "Import" my sql database I always get the fallowing error Fatal error: 
Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\import.lib.php on line 345
```

The database is kind of big 203MB and I archived it aiesecbu_achieve.sql.zip 55.8 MB

I can say that I`ve already tried this: [Fatal error: Maximum execution exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936314/fatal-error-maximum-execution-exceeded)
and modifying my php.ini

```
post_max_size = 400M
upload_max_filesize = 250M
memory_limit = 128M
```

I have uploaded my database for you to test it if you want(maybe it`s something wrong with it) and a screenshot

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cx9wava7sptf4km/mysql.jpg?dl=0

Comment: A much easier alternative: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Comment: I removed your dropbox link to your site backup. Thats got to be the **dumbest** think to do since **dumb met dumber**. Anybody could have downloaded that. The least you should do is change your admin password.

Comment: There is no problem because the website will be rebuilded from 0 and I need to import this just to have it as a sample and not lose anything like content...

Comment: Rnevius I used the plugin that you recommended and everything worked out just fine Thank You!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to use mysql console.

1. Run `cmd` command
2. Type `c:` or `d:` on command prompt. This will be based on your WAMP server installations.
3. Assuming you have installed wamp on D: drive.
4. `D:\>cd wamp`
5. `D:\wamp>cd bin`
6. `D:\wamp\bin>cd mysql`
7. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql>cd mysql15.1.36`
8. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36>cd bin`
9. `D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql15.1.36\bin>mysql.exe -u root`
10. `use database`
11. `source source.sql`

Bassicaly you login into mysql, `use database` determines which database you want to use, `source /source/to/source.sql` determines which sql you want to run. Pretty easy and efficient.

Comment: c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17>cd c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin

c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe

And i`ve got mysql> where i typed -u root

Printscr- https://www.dropbox.com/s/kswwmc9wahhljae/cmd.jpg?dl=0

Comment: when you were in mysql console, when you type "u -root", you should type "use name_of_your_database",enter then "source /path/to/your/sql.sql"

Comment: Skip steps 1-9 by clicking the [WAMP] icon -> "MySQL" -> "MySQL Console"

Answer (score 9):

As you have phpMyAdmin4.1.14 installed I assume you are using WAMPServer 2.5

In WAMPServer 2.5 the PHP resources used by phpMyAdmin are controlled from the phpMyAdmin alias config file. It was changed for exactly these situations, so you dont have to change the `php.ini` to add a ridiculously large values to parameters that effect your whole PHP environment.

So to increase the relevant paameters you would do this :-

Edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` which should look like this by default

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

Now change the parameters here, so they only effect what happens when you are running phpMyAdmin.

These are the parameters you should amend

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 500M      <-- and probably this
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 620        <-- this for a start
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```

But basically try a modification and see if it works, if not depending on the error amend the relevant parameter.

**Dont forget to restart Apache after each change you make to this file**

*Oh and dont forget to undo the changes you made to `php.ini`*

Comment: already tried this...haven`t worked but I have used the plugin that Rnevius recommended (dublicator) and I managed to move my website entirely from host to local. Thank you All!

Comment: You didn't say you had tried this. Remember, this will override the changes you made to `php.ini` so anything you did to `php.ini` will have been ignored.

Comment: Tried it while waiting for answers. The thing is that i just started working on this website after other several persons worked on it for some years and the database and pages inside the website are very mumbled and are poor organised so I decided to rebuild it.

Guys thank you for your fast answers!! Got to love stackoverflow. Hope i`ll get the same feedback from you!

Comment: I am almost positive I did this not too long ago and it worked. I moved about 6 months ago and now have a different computer. I took the values out of my old computer that DID work and tried to do the same thing on my new computer, but nope. I am getting the feeling that there is another file that might be overwriting this info. Any clue what it might be? Some user config file? (nothing I added, this WAMP is brand spanking new except for the above changes in the php.ini)

Comment: found it! C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf, thanks to @Evans Belloeil in another post

Comment: @BillyNair You are not supposed to make these changes in `PHP.INI` you make them in the file I mentioned on line 6 of my answer **`\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`** I didn't put a drive letter on as WAMPServer can be installed on any drive.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version of wamp server:

- Wampserver 2.5.17 32bits
- Apache 2.4.17/2.2.31
- PHP 5.6.14/7.0.0rc5/5.5.30/5.4.45/5.3.29
- MySQL 5.6.27/5.7.9/5.5.46/5.1.73/5.0.83
- PhPMyAdmin 4.5.0
- MysqlDumper 1.24.4 (W7 Pro 64bits)

try this out:
In `wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` file, just before the last statement `</Directory>` add four statements to obtain:

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 512M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 512M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 900
  php_admin_value max_input_time 900
</Directory>
```