# Phpmyadmin page doesn't load

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm currently workind with WAMPserver, but I have problems trying to acces to the phpmyadmin page, it just doesn't load.

I tryed every single solution that I could find (uninstalling and re-installing, uppdating apache2, changing the .conf file), but nothing seems to work. Oh, and I couldn't find the World Wide Web Publishing Service installed on my computer.

I'm working with Windows 10

Comment: Did you check your PHPMyAdmin folder, maybe you haven't it) What error do you get when trying to open PHPMyAdmin? And do you sure your other services/websites works?

Comment: Is Apache and MySQL running? Which *exact* error do you get when trying to access phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @TeymurMardaliyerLennon Yes, I have the folder. My other services run just fine, and the error I got is this: **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.6.4\libraries\php-gettext\streams.php**

Comment: @Qirel Yes, they are. The error I got was **Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 360 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.6.4\libraries\php-gettext\streams.php**

Comment: Did you tryed it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244924/maximum-execution-time-of-360-seconds-exceeded-in-c-wamp-apps-phpmyadmin4-1-14

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time you don't need to increase anything! just restart apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` and the problem is gone.